# asp.net core executing powershell some commands work while others return result 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following simple code that works and executes a powershell command in asp.net core website running on my cshtml.cs code behind page

`using System.Management.Automation;`

```
public void Execute()
{
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {    
        ps.AddScript("Get-Date");
        var results = ps.Invoke();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            string test = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This works i get the current date reported as a string and results variable contains a count of 1.
"7/16/2020 4:38:27 PM"

If i then change it to another command say

ps.AddScript("Get-WmiObject");
or
ps.AddScript("Get-LocalGroupMember -group my_local_group_name");

Then i get no results, results comes back as count of 0 ?? The only thing i can determine is that Get-Date is a single string where as the other commands Get-WmiObject and Get-LocalGroupMember are multiple lines of text in the outputs when i execute them from a normal Powershell window.

my goal is to be able to execute the Get-LocalGroupMember command and get it's output. Is there something else i'm missing or not doing in terms of Powershell commands ? why is it some commands are working and producing output and others are not ?

UPDATE:
So i was getting error in the error stream of the ps object it states

```
{The 'Get-LocalGroupMember' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts'.}
```

if i open a x86 Powershell window and run the Get-LocalGroupMember cmd  it gives me error

```
Get-LocalGroupMember : The term 'Get-LocalGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
```

running the Get-LocalGroupMember cmd in a regular Powershell window (that is x64) the cmd runs perfect.

My project is set to x64 :( so am failing to understand why asp.net is using what seems to me a 32bit version of powershell. That's what i need i need to be able to execute my powershell cmds as x64 because Get-LocalGroupMember cmd is only available in Powershell x64 .

Please Help ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

so i ended up having to do the following for some reason in order to get certian commands like Get-LocalGroupMember to work, other commands like Get-Date don't require the import, and even though on my system i had execution policy unrestricted, whenever i use c# in asp.net and checked errors on my ps object it was acting like it wasn't and would not let me run a script using AddScript. So i had to be administrator running visual studio and use set-executionpolicy like below, then be able to add the localaccounts module to be able to use Get-LocalGroupMember.. again if i open a x64 Powershell window on the system i can run Get-LocalGroupMember fine. seems c# is doing some weird things with the Powershell shell that it is creating and running in memory. Anyway hopefully this saves someone else time if they run into the same situation.

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force");
                ps.AddScript("Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts");
                ps.AddScript("Get-LocalGroupMember -group your_local_group_name | Out-String");
                var results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    string test = result.ToString();
                    TestText = test;
                }
            }
```